# How to verify galera is synced

Tags: mysql, replication, galera, multi-master

I have been using mysql master:master replication and was always able to check the status of replication using this command:
`mysql > show slave status\G`
I was able to see this in the show slave status command:
`Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Seconds_Behind_Master: 0`
The seconds_behind_master always let me know if I was behind on one of my servers.

I am not using galera and am not sure how to verify if everything is up to date.
I have come across this article ["Monitoring Cluster Status"](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/monitoringthecluster.html)
I realize I can use this command to see how many nodes are in the cluster:
`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size';`

But I am not sure if this command if good enough to tell whether or not they are exactly up to date:
`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_local_state_comment';`
This command currently show synced but I cannot tell if this is the best way to tell if I am good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `wsrep_local_state_comment`, `wsrep_ready`, and `wsrep_connected` show the correct values, then that particular node is good.

There's no `Seconds_Behind_Master` equivalent, because Galera is synchronous -- a healthy node can't be lagging, by definition and by design... a slow node slows down all the others, it doesn't lag behind them.

Comment: For the `wsrep_local_state_comment` What would be a correct value?  I am currently seeing it set to synced.

Comment: add `wsrep_cluster_size` which should be equal to the number of nodes of the cluster

Comment: @Som3guy yes, `'Synced'` is correct.

Comment: @jerichorivera it should equal the number of nodes, but if it isn't, that does not necessarily mean *this node* has a problem.  With 3 nodes, if "node x" suddenly returns a value of "2" here, then "node x" would actually be one of the *good* nodes... So, while useful information, it doesn't really give you any new information about *this* node.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are right

Comment: Although there is no seconds_behind_master, you can check the wsrep_flow_control_sent and wsrep_flow_control_recv values.  If these are non-zero then someone is having problems keeping up - either the node or the network.  Then you need to consider increasing the wsrep_slave_threads to 2x#CPU though that can cause replication errors in extreme cases (eg databases with external key constraints)